# Shortcode issues

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am using

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode'); 
 add_shortcode('shtcode1', array(&$this, 'form_test'), 10, 1); 

fuction form_test(){
  echo 'test';
}
```

I am using the above mentioned code to add data in the text widget.

But what I notice is the data is not returned inside the `div` textwidget it come just inside `div` with the classs `complementary`.

How to get data inside textwidget `div`?

```
<div role="complementary" class="content-sidebar widget-area" id="content-sidebar">
    in apply test
    <aside class="widget widget_text" id="text-2">
        <h1 class="widget-title">Apply</h1>
        <div class="textwidget"></div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: I really didn't understand your question. What output you get when used `[shtcode1]` inside your text widget?

Comment: The output is such that text "in apply test" is displayed first, followed by the header tags "Apply" and then the text widget which is empty. I wanted the content to be placed inside the text widget div.

Comment: @user3230561 Do `return 'test'` instead `echo 'test';`. See @brasofilo duplicated question.

Comment: Thanks...I am building an html form inside the shortcode. Is there any easy way to add form inside shortcode. I can see only one way that is building the whole form string inside a php variable and then returning that variable.